# Is it faster to alter multiple columns in the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

Is it any faster to add or drop multiple columns in one query, rather than executing a query for each column? For example, is this:

```
ALTER TABLE t2 DROP COLUMN c, DROP COLUMN d;
```

any faster than this?

```
ALTER TABLE t2 DROP COLUMN c;
ALTER TABLE t2 DROP COLUMN d;
```

Comment: Do you do this operation intensively and under hard load?

Comment: @Bencaine Does it matter? I mean how often are you going to need to do this. Almost never, right?

Comment: Measure it and find out...

Comment: I would guess that doing it in one operation is faster, but you should really test both ways.  If the table is empty, then it won't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's faster. You only have to make one call to the database API, and it only has to parse the query once.

However, for `ALTER TABLE` queries, performance usually isn't a concern. You shouldn't be doing this frequently, only when you redesign your schema.

But if your question were about `UPDATE` queries, for instance, it would probably be significant. E.g. you should do:

```
UPDATE table
SET col1 = foo, col2 = bar
WHERE <condition>;
```

rather than

```
UPDATE table
SET col1 = foo
WHERE <condition>;

UPDATE table
SET col2 = bar
WHERE <condition>;
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it should be faster to run a single ALTER TABLE statement than two.

In my experience (with InnoDB on 5.1 and 5.5), MySQL doesn't seem to modify the table "in place". MySQL actually creates a new table, as copy of the old table with the specified modifications.

Two separate statements would require MySQL to do that copy operation twice.

With a single statement, you give MySQL the opportunity to make all the changes with just one copy operation. (I don't know the details of the MySQL internals, but it's possible that MySQL actually does the copy two times.)

Other database engines (MyISAM et al.) may get processed differently.

---

I believe the InnoDB plugin and/or newer versions of InnoDB in the MySQL (>5.5) have some algorithms other than the "copy" method, at least for some changes, which allow for the table to still be available while the ALTER TABLE is running (for read queries). But I don't know all the details.